# Route guard while using ionic + react

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to redirect the unauthenticated user to `/login`. I have a property in my context called `loggedIn`, when it is false I want to make a redirect to `HomePage` i.e `"/"`.

I just got confused due to the route structure. I'm seeing something like a protected route everywhere.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet, IonSplitPane } from "@ionic/react";
import { IonReactRouter } from "@ionic/react-router";
import { setupConfig } from "@ionic/react";
import { Plugins, Capacitor } from "@capacitor/core";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home";

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import "@ionic/react/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import "@ionic/react/css/normalize.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/structure.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/typography.css";

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import "@ionic/react/css/padding.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/display.css";
import "../src/utils/spacing.css";

/* Theme variables */
import "./theme/variables.css";

/* Components */
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import SideMenu from "./components/SideMenu/SideMenu";
import LoginPage from "./pages/Login/Login";
import SignupPage from "./pages/Signup/Signup";
import Create from "./pages/Create/Create";
import Edit from "./pages/Edit/Edit";
import { AuthContext, AuthProvider } from "./providers/context/AuthContext";


const App: React.FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <AuthProvider>
        <IonReactRouter>
          <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
            <SideMenu />
            <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
              <Route path="/dashboard/:name" component={Dashboard} exact />
              <Route path="/dashboard/Edit/:id" component={Edit} exact />
              // if !user navigate to login component
              <Route path="/create" component={Create} exact />
              <Route path="/signup" component={SignupPage} exact />
              <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
              <Redirect from="/dashboard" to="/dashboard/Home" exact />
            </IonRouterOutlet>
          </IonSplitPane>
        </IonReactRouter>
      </AuthProvider>
    </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be useful for anyone: is solved it by using the Private Route and pubic Route trick

I Created a component called `PrivateRoute.tsx` and added the following:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { EnrolleeContext } from "../providers/context/EnrolleeContext";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const { loggedIn } = useContext(EnrolleeContext);

  return (
    // Show the component only when the user is logged in
    // Otherwise, redirect the user to /signin page
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        loggedIn ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Also created a Public Route, added restricted to be able to `restrict Components` if `restricted == true`, meaning the Route is Private, if false, otherwise.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { EnrolleeContext } from "../providers/context/EnrolleeContext";

const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, restricted, ...rest }: any) => {
  const { loggedIn } = useContext(EnrolleeContext);

  return (
    // restricted = false meaning public route
    // restricted = true meaning restricted route
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        loggedIn && restricted ? (
          <Redirect to="/dashboard/Home" />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PublicRoute;
```

Updated `App.tsx`

```
<PublicRoute restricted={false} component={Home} path="/" exact />
          <PublicRoute
            restricted={true}
            component={LoginPage}
            path="/login"
            exact
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            component={Dashboard}
            path="/dashboard/:name"
            exact
          />
          <PrivateRoute component={Create} path="/create" exact />
          <PublicRoute
            restricted={false}
            component={ForgotPassword}
            path="/forgot-password"
            exact
          />
```

Other Routes like `forgot password is open to the` public`, while Create is Private, so it is at your own discretion.